# English, French and German Books Permutation and Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A language teacher has 10 different books of which 5 are English, 4 are French and 1 is German. Find the number of ways she can arrange them on the shelf if
(i) the books can be arranged in any order,
(ii) the books in each language are kept together.
(iii) The teacher decides to reduce the number of books to 5. Find the number of ways she can select these 5 books from the 10 different books if she is to keep at least one book in each language.

My answers:

(i)  10! = 3 628 800

(ii) EEEEE FFFF G

$3!\times 5!\times4! = 17 280$ (3! different ways to arrange 3 different language books, 5! ways to arrange 5 different English books, 4! ways to arrange 4 different French books)

(iii) 3 cases as follows:

EFGEE   => $ 5P1 \times 4P1 \times 4P2 \times 5! = 28800$

EFGEF   => $ 5P1 \times 4P1 \times 4P1 \times 3P1 \times 5! \times 2 = 28800$

EFGFF   => $ 5P1 \times 4P1 \times 4P1 \times 3P2 \times 5! = 14400$

28800 + 28800 + 14400 = 72000

I would like to check if all of my answers are correct? If not what have I done wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: Are all of the english books identical?  Or are they distinct?  Assuming they are in fact distinct, then your answers to (i) and (ii) are correct, however your answers for (iii) run the error of incorrectly attributing some significance to the order in which you collected the books to be used prior to arranging them on the shelf.

Comment: I assume they are distinct since it mentioned 10 different books. For (iii), can you kindly elaborate more on how I should do it ?

Comment: For the case of `EFGEE` for instance, what you *should* have done is pick which three english books are to be used *simultaneously*, in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways, then picking which french book and the german book and then arranged them... for a total of $\binom{5}{3}\cdot 4\cdot 5! = 4800$ cases.  Also, for readability, don't bother with writing $\binom{n}{1}$ or $nP1$... just write $n$.

Comment: Isn't (iii) also using permutation since different books?

Comment: It is... but that doesn't mean that binomial coefficients can't appear in the calculations.  If you have trouble seeing how you overcounted, repeat the question but where we have only the five english books and no other books of any other kind.  We want to arrange five of the books making sure that at least one of each category appears.  According to your broken logic, it would have been $5P1~\times~5!$ which is more than the total number of ways of having put the five books out in the first place. Again, this is because you are incorrectly applying significance to which was the "first" chosen

Comment: Or even, you might have said it was $5P1~\times 4P4~\times 5!$ which is even more overcounting since not only are you seeming to assign relevance to the first of those chosen prior to choosing their places on the shelf but also assigning significance to the order in which the rest of the books are put into the staging area prior to being shelved.  If all we care about is how the final outcome of how books appear on the shelf, then the order in which things happen before the books arrive in their final resting spot on the shelf is largely irrelevant.

Comment: There are only $10P5=30240$ ways to have put five books out in the first place.  You should have gotten $\binom{5}{3}\cdot 4\cdot 5! + \binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{2}\cdot 5!+5\cdot\binom{4}{3}\cdot 5! = 14400$.  For an alternate approach for (iii) I suggest inclusion-exclusion, removing those outcomes who were missing one or more of the categories, adding back those who are missing two categories, subtracting missing three, giving $10P5 - 5P5 - 6P5 - 9P5 + 0+0+5P5 - 0 = 14400$, noting how you can't miss too many categories and still have enough books to fill all five spots

Comment: ok thank you so much. Got it.